# In how many ways can i partition a stick

Tags: combinatorics

I have a stick (or a ruler) of 10 cm length.
I want to cut the stick into pieces.
Each cm (1 cm, 2cm, 3cm, ... 0 cm) is a possible cutting point.

In how many different ways can i cut the stick?
One way would be to cut at every cm, so I get 10 parts.
Another would be to cut two 1cm pieces, and the rest 2cm pieces = 6 parts

Is there a formula for this? All i know is that it's not a normal permutation...

edit:

A 1cm piece cut at 1cm is different from a 1cm piece cut from 9cm, even when the rest is partitioned the same way.

Comment: Wrong website :) _Mathematica_ != _Mathematics_

Comment: If every integer point 1cm through 9cm is either a cut or not a cut then there are 2^9 == 512 ways to make the cuts.

Comment: `IntegerPartitions`?

Comment: @Öskå oh  no. thanks for pointing it out. will never happen again!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can you explain the underlying systematic behind it? (If you make a post, ill accept it as an answer)

Comment: This is actually a difficult problem, and has an entire topic devoted to it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29

Comment: I'm not sure in what sense it's a difficult problem: you can count the partitions of 10 by hand.

Comment: You did not specify the problem fully enough: is it the same for you to make 1 cut at 1 cm or 1 cut at 9 cm (you obtain a 1-cm and a 9-cm piece), or do you consider these as two different ways to cut the stick? If you choose the latter, then @Mr.Wizard is correct.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I mean the general problem is difficult, and there's no elementary formula for it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is a *partitions* problems. In partitions the order of the summands do not matter. That is $1 + 8 + 1 = 10$ and $8 + 1 + 1 = 10$ are counted as the same partition, but they correspond to different ways of cutting the ruler. The first $1 + 8 + 1 = 10$ corresponds to cutting a 1cm and 9cm while the second $8 + 1 + 1 = 10$ corresponds to cutting a 8cm and 9cm. The questions as posed is **how many ways to cut the ruler**, this is actually a *compositions* problem. Like Mr.Wizard said the solution is $2^9 = 512$. This is because of each of 1cm, 2cm, ..., 9cm there can either be a cut or not. Thus we have two options (to either cut or not) and we do this 9 times. Therefore we get $2^9$.

See below for more on compositions. Compositions are a much easier problem than partitions.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)

Comment: So If I chose to either cut, not cut or delete a piece (like throw it away without cutting, making the stick smaller), i get the solution with 3^9?

Comment: You have to be careful with that. We are cutting at the marks 1 cm, 2 cm, etc. But we would be throwing away actual parts of the stick. So, if you choose to "delete" at 3 cm for example what are you deleting? The part before 3 cm or the part after 3 cm? So, it is not as simple as just adding another option and making it $3^9$.

Answer (score -1):

There are two interpretations of your problem: if cutting into $[0,1]$ and $[1,10]$ is different than cutting into $[0,9]$ and $[9,10]$, then as was mentioned in the comments this is a counting principle problem: you decide independently which of nine points to cut or not cut at, in the same way as given five shirts, three pairs of shoes, and two pairs of trousers you have thirty choices of outfits.

But what seems to be a more natural interpretation is that the two cuttings I mentioned are the same, in which case this is a partition problem, the general type being to determine how many ways we can write an integer $n$ as a sum of smaller integers. Your problem is a partition problem because the pieces of ruler you come out with must have integer lengths summing to 10.

The easiest way to compute partition numbers by hand is to use Euler's pentagonal number theorem, which is described on the Wikipedia page. It's also possible, though it'll probably take a little while, to compute this partition number directly: you have partitions $10,9+1,8+2,8+1+1,7+3,7+2+1,7+1+1+1,6+4,...,5+4+1,...,5+1+1+1+1+1,4+4+2,...,1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1$.

The thing you must be careful about is not to list any partitions twice: this is why I wrote them down with pieces in decreasing order, which will guarantee you don't write, say, both $6+4$ and $4+6$. You should end up with the [answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) to life, the universe, and everything, so it's surely a worthwhile problem.